# Tooltip arrow doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with my tooltip.
I want my tooltip to be like this:

[image]

But my result is like this:

[image]

Below is my HTML & Jquery code:

```
 <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;" align="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-container="body" title="segment" >

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

I'm using bootstrap version 3.3.2.

Really appreciate your help guys.

Thank you.

Comment: i'm using google chrome latest update..

Comment: you need to over write existing styles with new one.

Comment: is it the default tooltip is the result i got? because the example in the bootstrap web page using the black color tooltip.

Comment: you should add a `jsfiddle` with your issue

Answer (score 1):

I think it might have something to do with the fact that it is inside a `<tr>` element. This effects the positioning because of the styles on the `<tr>` which force it to an unexpected position

a quick solution, or maybe just to check if that is the case it to add the tooltip to a `<span>` inside the `<td>`

```js
$(function () {
    $('.table1 td').tooltip({title:"test",placement:"bottom"});
    $('.table2 td span').tooltip({title:"test",placement:"bottom"});
});
```

```css
.container{
  margin-top:20px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered table1">
      <tr>
        <td>
            standard td - tooltip inside of tr tag
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered table2">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>
            tooltip item wrapped in span tag
            </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i try @gerdi but the result is same..:(

Answer (score 0):

Try with this demo, will get your required tooltip. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/mu4tk734/1/)

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
       title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on right"
       class="black-tooltip">Tooltip on bottom</a>
```

Comment: sorry @stanze..the result i got still the same as previous

Comment: Even check the files included.

Comment: i already tried the demo..in the demo, it works fine but not in my code.. i'm not sure what is happening right now..

Comment: @eikaz, might be you are included respected files for the same. :)

Comment: right now i wooried if the tooltip for bootstrap is conflict with jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok, i am using this html in the example

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;" align="left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-container="body" title="segment" >
      TEST
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o6ncwhsb/1/

**Are you importing JQuery UI or another plugin for tooltips?** Maybe it could be overwriting css styles. I had a similar problem time ago...

Comment: yes..i already have jquery-ui.css..is this file causing this problem? how can i skip the css in the file? i want to use the css in the bootstrap

Comment: What is happening is that you are executing tooltip plugin from jQuery UI instead of Bootstrap tooltip, so you should avoid Tooltip import from jQuery UI creating a custom jQuery UI import file: https://jqueryui.com/download/ (uncheck widget tooltip)

Comment: i already have jquery-ui.css, jquery-ui.min.css, jquery-ui.structure.css, jquery-ui.structure.min, jquery-ui.theme & jquery-ui.theme.min.. how do i skip this css and use the css in the bootstrap css for tooltip?

Comment: Best option is to remove Tooltip from jQuery UI, if you cant do that then check this to try a workaround: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6303